# Does India have 101 COVID deaths per million population?

Tags: mortality, covid-19

The [Worldometer COVID-19 statistics by country](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries) currently shows

- USA: 855 deaths per million population
- UK: 891 deaths per million population
- France: 829 deaths per million population

but India only has 101 deaths per million population

I can not believe this statistic: India has a large population and I didn't think India's healthcare infrastructure is that advanced to tackle such issues.

Is this figure accurate?

Comment: Reporting standards what constitutes death from Covid [vary](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/11/17/europe/russia-coronavirus-pandemic-excess-deaths-intl/index.html) by country. Also, there's the issue of population age. https://www.bbc.com/news/52311014

Comment: Note according to the statistics, India has about a third of the testing coverage of those other countries.

Comment: A bit more in-depth discussion here on the variations in reporting: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0141076820956802 although it doesn't cover India

Comment: But there's a [news article](https://www.euronews.com/2020/10/12/india-has-millions-of-covid-19-cases-but-why-is-its-death-rate-low) on the possible reasons for such low reporting in India. Besides the young population, 4 of 5 deaths in India don't even get a cause assigned.

Comment: And India apparently doesn't release enough info to calculate excess deaths https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-53773070 (Even Russia is more transparent [in this respect](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-russia-mortality-idINKBN2652CO).)

Comment: India is probably not unique here among the low-income countries. Globally 2 of 3 deaths don't get registered (and thus don't get assigned a cause). https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2020/09/25/914073217/why-the-pandemic-could-change-the-way-we-record-deaths

Comment: There is a big big big difference between "India has the least deaths" and "India has reported the least deaths".

Comment: Obesity has also been shown to be a big factor AFAIK.

Comment: There are many countries that have claimed fewer deaths per million:  https://ncov2019.live/  Norway, Japan, and New Zealand would be three with reasonably credible reporting (more credible than India).

Comment: Can you adjust the title to make it more clear what you're really asking, in view of the latest comments (and answer). I take it you're questioning the 100 deaths per million in India. Do you really think that's also the lowest figure reported by any country?

Comment: I don't that's why I asked

Comment: Better comparisons might be with large countries.  For example from that table and countries over 100 million population (and death rates per million), there are USA (853), Mexico (835), Brazil (822), Russia (289), India (101), Philippines (77), Egypt (65), Indonesia (64), Bangladesh (41), Pakistan (37), Japan (18), Ethiopia (15), Nigeria (6), China (3).  The real question is whether you trust these numbers.  But it does not seem India is at either end of the list

Comment: Why is your title "Why does India have the lowest reported death per million?" when you have submitted nothing to support this claim.  Who is claiming it???

Comment: I put the stats in the subject

Comment: This question needs a major clean up. I submitted an edit for one approach, and then rolled it back because I am not sure if that is what the OP wants. It also undermines the existing answer, which is never desirable.

Comment: @Buraian: Please be careful. No-one thinks India has the lowest figure, so that shouldn't be the question. Don't confuse "deaths per million population" with "deaths per million infected".

Comment: @T.Sar - that, I believe, is what the OP is trying to find out...

Answer (score 4):

India does not have the lowest reported number of deaths per million:
According to the [same source](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) the OP linked to, when sorting by population

> China: population: 1,439,323,776 total deaths: 4,634 deaths per 1M pop: 3
> India: population: 1,385,752,793 total deaths:139,473 deaths per 1M pop: 101
> USA: population: 331,828,037 total deaths: 283,072 deaths per 1M pop: 853
> Indonesia: population: 274,748,198 total deaths: 17,479 deaths per 1M pop: 64

I won't attempt to judge how credible/complete all of these numbers are. But the numbers India reported are neither on the topmost nor on the lowest end - there are countries which have reported more deaths, and there are countries which have reported less deaths.

---

If we are talking about the rate of deaths per confirmed cases:
[India](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/india/) currently reports

> closed cases 9,155,516
> deaths 139,227

which is ~1.54% death per case (rounded to 2% in the UI).

There are several countries that report less deaths, e.g. [Austria](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/austria/):

> closed cases 247,426
> deaths 3,651

~1.47% (rounded to 1% in the UI)

both as of 2020-12-04. Still close, but lower.

And then, of course, there are several countries which have not reported any deaths due to covid19 at all, e.g. [Vanuatu](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/vanuatu/), which had exactly 1 case and no death.

Comment: OP is referring to deaths as a percentage of the overall population, not deaths as a percentage of those infected.

Comment: @F1Krazy agreed, I have added the numbers per population of the 4 most populous countries, to demonstrate that India does not report the lowest number there either

Comment: @F1Krazy Considering that they are #2 in the world population wise and have around 4 times the population of the #3 country I am not sure that is a fair comparison. Looks like they have about 17.7% of the world population.

Comment: @JoeW All I said is that that's the metric the OP wants to look at. Whether it's a valid or meaningful metric is another matter entirely.